# ValueError at watch

Tags: python, django, django-views

This code gave me this error.

what's the problem?

When I click on the add button, it gives this error:

(The error returns to the last line of the add function.)

> AttributeError at /add/1/
> 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id'
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/1/

When I click on the watch list link (in layout.html), it shows this:
(The error returns to the first line of the watchlist function.)

> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'zahrashokri'.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/watchlist/zahrashokri/

thanks for any idea:)

**code**:

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def watchlist(request, username):
    products = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, pk=username)
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {'products': products})


@login_required(login_url="login")
def add(request, productid):
    item = get_object_or_404(List, pk=productid)
    #user = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, user)
    user_Watchlist, __ = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_Watchlist.watchitem.add(item)
    return redirect('watchlist', Watchlist.user.id)

@login_required(login_url="login")
def remove(request, pid):
    list_ = Watchlist.objects.get(pk = pid)
    messages.success(request, f"{list_.watchitem.title} is 
           deleted from your watchlist.")
    list_.delete()
    return redirect("index")
```

urls.py:

```
    path("watchlist/<str:username>/", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
    path("add/<int:productid>/", views.add, name="add"),
    path("remove/<int:pid>/", views.remove, name="remove"),
```

product_detail.html:

```
{% if list in watchlist_items %}
    <a href="{% url 'remove' p.id %}">
        <button type = "button">remove from watchlist</button>
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'add' product.id %}">
        <button type = "button">add to watchlist</button>
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

watchlist.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

{% if products %}
    {% for product in products %}
        <img src= {{ product.image.url }} alt = "{{product.title}}"><br>
        <a><a>Product:</a>{{ product.title }}</a><br>
        <a><a>Category: </a>{{ product.category }}</a><br>
        <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ product.first_bid }} $ </a> <br>
    

        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">View Product</a>

        <form action="{% url 'remove' product.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Remove</button>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No products in watchlist</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

layout.html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category_2' 
      %}">Category</a>
</li>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'watchlist' 
              user.username %}">My WatchList</a>
   </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you show the full error? Your code doesn't explicitly show a field named `id`. Is the error coming from your template?

Comment: I think the problem is with this line     return redirect('watchlist', Watchlist.user). you need to pass id not user object, try this     return redirect('watchlist', Watchlist.user.id)

Comment: @DanielleM. I changed the question and made it more complete. Please check again.

Comment: @VinitaSonakiya I tried and it gave an error and I corrected the question. Please check (the error is also mentioned in the question).

Comment: Replace `redirect('watchlist', Watchlist.user.id)` by `redirect('watchlist',  username=request.user.username)`

Comment: Can you share your models.py ?

Comment: @Zatigem Thanks. I managed to solve this bug but there is one more small problem. If you want, please check this link.[https://stackoverflow.com/q/77579478/22267432]