# How to change the button name after performing the corresponding action?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

In this code, the action is performed completely, but after adding the product to the list::

1- The button doesn't change its name from Add to Remove.

2- The product information that's in watchlist.html is not displayed, that is, the output's:

> Products:
> Category:
> First Bid: $

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def watchlist(request, username):
    products = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = username)
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {'products': products})


@login_required(login_url="login")
def add(request, productid):
    product_id = request.GET.get('productid', False)
    watch = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = request.user.username)
  
    for items in watch:
        if (items.watch_list.all) == int(productid):  
            return watchlist(request, request.user.username)
        else:
            return remove(request, productid)
    

    new_watch = Watchlist(product_id, user=request.user.username)
    new_watch.save()
    messages.success(request, "The product has been added to your WatchList.")
    return product_detail(request, productid)


@login_required(login_url="login")
def remove(request, pid):
    list_ = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, pk = pid)
    messages.success(request, "The product was removed from your WatchList.")
    list_.delete()
    return redirect("index")
```

product_detail.html:

```
{% if product in watch %}
    <form method= "get" action = "{% url 'remove' product.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type = "submit" value = "{{ product.id }}"  name = "productid" >Remove from Watchlist</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form method= "get" action = "{% url 'add' product.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type = "submit" value = "{{ product.id }}"  name = "productid" >Add to Watchlist</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

watchlist.html:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% if products %}
        
        <a><a>Product:</a>{{ product.watchlist.title }}</a><br>
        <a><a>Category: </a>{{ product.category }}</a><br>
        <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ product.first_bid }} $ </a> <br>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
path("watchlist/<str:username>/", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
path("add/<int:productid>/", views.add, name="add"),
path("remove/<int:pid>/", views.remove, name="remove"),
```

Comment: Where does the `product_detail(request, productid)` is defined ?

Comment: @Zatigem product_detail is a function and here we go from add function to this function. There is no code related to this issue in product_detail in the view. That's why I didn't put it here.
However, the watchlist in product_detail.html It has codes and you can see them.

Comment: Could you please share more details, at least the `product_detail()` code please ?